# Pandas sub-selection of groups using criteria

Tags: python, pandas

I have multiple websites with users accessing them at different dates. I only want to have websites that were accessed first in a specific time-frame:

```
sites = db.groupby('websitename')
newWebsites = (sites['date'].min() >= '2018-02-17') &
              (sites['date'].min() < '2018-02-24')
```

This gives me a series object with a `True` or `False` for every website:

```
websitename
google.com                                     False
facebook.com                                   False
hooli.com                                      True
Name: date, Length: 70, dtype: bool
```

What I'd like to do is calculate the amount of users these websites have in the following weeks. What I then do is group by `websitename` and `date`:

```
siteDate = db.groupby(['websitename', 'date'])
```

Calling `siteDate['ga:Users'].sum()` already gives me what I want:

```
websitename                                  date   
google.com                                   2018-04-03    1
facebook.com                                 2018-04-07    1
hooli.com                                    2018-02-17    1
                                             2018-02-20    1
                                             2018-03-07    1
                                             2018-03-08    3
Name: users, Length: 794, dtype: int64
```

But now I only want specific sites (the ones specified in newWebsites. In this case `hooli.com`).

Now I'd like to select all websites that have `True` in `newWebsites` from `siteDate`. I tried:

```
siteDate[newWebsites]
```

But this returns an error: `'Columns not found: False, True'`

Which I understand, because pandas is looking in `siteDate` for the columns `True`and `False` which do not exist. But how do I select the right websites then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `[]` operator on a DataFrame chooses columns by default.  To choose rows, use `.loc[]`:

```
siteDate['ga:Users'].sum().loc[newWebsites]
```

Comment: But because I have a groupby Object this results in the following error:
    AttributeError: Cannot access callable attribute 'loc' of 'DataFrameGroupBy' objects, try using the 'apply' method

Comment: @HansBambel: Sorry, try my update now.  And if it doesn't quite work, play with it a bit.  Your actual use case is slightly complicated by the MultiIndex labels it has, and you haven't given us an MVCE, so I can't promise you 100% working code, but this is the general idea.

Comment: Thank you for the ideas! I made it work with `siteDate['ga:Users'].sum().loc[newWebsites[newWebsites].index]`